# Starling / Stage3d unload game from stage

Tags: apache-flex, stage3d, starling-framework

I have a flex app which loads at a point a stage3D (starling) game.
All works nice until this point, I am able to hide the app and display only the game layer, but the issue arrives when the game is finished and I want to return to the flex app and remove the game from the stage.

I did tried to stop the game and remove all children from stage3d but this does not work ok, and next time I try to re-display the game it does not show.

Here is some code I am using

Adding the game and starting it (all works fine)

```
starlingGame                = new Starling(Game, this.systemManager.stage);
starlingGame.antiAliasing   = 0;
starlingGame.start();
starlingGame.showStats      = true;
// this event is dispatched when stage3D is set up
starlingGame.stage3D.addEventListener(Event.CONTEXT3D_CREATE, onContextCreated);
```

Here is how I try to remove/unload the game
- for some reasons this works the first time, but afterwords the code above does not make the game display for the second time :(

```
starlingGame.stop();
starlingGame.removeEventListener(Event.CONTEXT3D_CREATE, onContextCreated);
starlingGame.stage.removeChildren();
starlingGame    = null;
```

Comment: Its hard to tell as we do not see the code where you add all the children. At least from your description of now showing again the stage I'd say you are not adding the children a second time.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The children get added inside the Game class, and since this gets re-instantiated as the first time all should be the same. I did have checked and the children get re-added. I have managed to fix it by hacking it using:  starlingGame.stage.visible = false; and re-displaying it when I need it one more time.